# TableView Data Not Reloading Swift

Tags: swift, swift3

I am working on restaurant app where i need to get all restaurant type..i successfully get all data but tableview not reloading..

```
var arrSubMenu = [ResataurantType]()

//TableView Datasource And Delegate Method
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    print(arrSubMenu.count)
    return arrSubMenu.count
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell: leftMenuTableViewCell = 
    tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "tableCell") as! 
    leftMenuTableViewCell
    cell.name.text = self.arrSubMenu[indexPath.row].type
    return cell
}

func getRestaurantType() {
    let manager = AFHTTPSessionManager()
    manager.requestSerializer = AFJSONRequestSerializer()
    manager.get(RESTAURANTTYPE, parameters: nil, progress: nil, success: { 
        (operation, responseObj) in
        if let objDic = responseObj as? [String:Any] {
            if let objArray = objDic["RESTAURANT_TYPE"] as? NSArray {
                for objType in objArray {
                    let ObjRestaurant = ResataurantType()
                    if let objString = objType as? String {
                        ObjRestaurant.type = objString
                    }
                    self.arrSubMenu.append(ObjRestaurant)
                }
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    self.tableView.reloadData()
                }
            }
        }
    }) { (operation, error) in
        print(error)
    }
}
```

I call this function in ViewDidLoad() but still i can't polulate tableview with record

Comment: Have you set the tableView's delegate and dataSource to this class of yours?

Comment: @RakshithNandish yes i have set it..i get arrSubMenu.count total  in numberOfRowsInSection but cellForRowAt Not executed..

Comment: `arrSubMenu.count` is probably `0`.

Comment: @OzgurVatansever I get arrSubMenu.count but cellForRowAt not executed..actually i am confused if i get numberOfRowsInSection then why cellForRowAt not executed

Answer (score 1):

-These can be possible reason from my person experience

1. TableView's  dataSource don't set to self.
   -Verification :- Break point on tableView Data Source & Delegate methods.
2. your arrSubMenu array don't contain the single value.
   -Verification:- Break point & print the arrSubMenu before reloading the tableView.

Answer (score 0):

You have just to enter:

First a IBOutlet:

```
@IBOutlet var tableView : UITableView
```

In viewDidLoad:

```
tableView.dataSource = self //OR connection between tableView in storyboard and tableView in swift class
```

Comment: Thank you for reply but datasource connection is ok.if i take static array then all work perfectly but when i get data from API it does not work..

Answer (score 0):

When are you calling getRestaurantType() ?   Could it be that it is called before the tableview's datasource is assigned ?   That could make the tableview appear empty although the underlying data is present.  And, unless you call reloadData() at some other point in the program, it will not refresh itself.

Answer (score 0):

Replace below at cell for row at index method

```
let cell = 
tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "tableCell" ,for: indexPath)as! 
leftMenuTableViewCellenter
```